# I can't get all the html data from beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im new in webscraping and i wanted to get just a text from a google page (basically the date of a soccer match), but the soup doesnt get all the html (im gessing beacause of request) so i can't find it, I know it can be beacause of google using javascript and I should use selenium chromedriver, but the thing is that I need the code to be usable on an another computer so it cant really use it..

heres the code :

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a = "Newcastle"
url ="https://www.google.com/search?q=" + a + "+next+match"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

print(soup)

for a in soup.findAll('div') :
    print(soup.get_text())
```

what i wanna find is

```
"<span class="imso_mh__lr-dt-ds">17/12, 13:30</span>"
```

it has

```
"//*[@id="sports-app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[2]"
```

as xpath

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `User-Agent` header when requesting the page from Google:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


a = "Newcastle"
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + a + "+next+match&hl=en"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

next_match = soup.select_one('[data-entityname="Match Header"]')
for t in next_match.select('[aria-hidden="true"]'):
    t.extract()

text = next_match.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
Club Friendlies · Dec 17, 13:30 Newcastle VS Vallecano
```